# Query firestore on the server with auth info in a nuxt app

Tags: firebase, firebase-authentication, google-cloud-firestore, nuxt.js

I plan to query some data from Firestore within the `fetch()` method that Nuxt provides and then send it to the store. The problem is that the query requires the Firebase Auth info (the Firestore rules more precise), and afaik will the Firebase Auth not yet be connected or have loaded the active user since that happens client side. So that would mean that the query wouldn't have the auth info? How would I go about solving this? I have looked around and found that you could use cookies to store the Firebase Auth id and then within `nuxtServerInit()` in the store, load the user and get the correct uid and so forth, but Firebase will still not know about the user and I haven't found a way to load the user into Firebase Auth on the server side using the id from the cookie.

Any help would be really appreciated! (I released this got quite messy but hopefully you guys get the main point)

Worth nothing that I'm using Google as the sign in provider.

**UPDATE:**

I've done some digging and found that you can get the `idToken` and `accessToken` from the `AuthCredential` you get back after successful sign in. I think you could store those instead in a cookie and then sign in the user on the server using `signInWithCredential()` and pass a new `GoogleAuthProvider` that you could create with `GoogleAuthProvider.credential(idToken, accessToken)` using the tokens from the cookie.

Again, I'm not sure if this is safe to do or the correct way but I think it should work at least because now Firebase would now about the user already on the server side and therefore should the call to Firestore be no problem regarding the auth info.

I'm not able to test this right now but some thoughts on this would be great, thanks!

Still not able to test it but would like someone thoughts on this.

Comment: I am doing something similar. With your suggested solution, how will you access the stored cookie info from thee nuxt server ? I think you are correct though, you would need to also sign in on the server as well. I have used the official nuxt firebase module, however, when you need to access the current user server side, things become experimental... Here is a issue I posted on github on the same topic... https://github.com/nuxt-community/firebase-module/issues/141 and also here https://github.com/nuxt-community/firebase-module/issues/164